# Unpacking fields from nested objects passed as a parameter

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How can I unpack nested object passed as a parameter? I want to unpack age from the object how can I do that?

```
const user = {
  id: 42,
  username: "usrname",
  info: {
    fullName: "John",
    age: 15
  }
};

function foo({ username: usrnam, info }) {
  return `${usrnam} ${info} `;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can destructure any level as:

```
{ username: usrnam, info: { age } }
```

or, if you don't want to assign to a new variable name then:

```
{ username, info: { age } }
```

```js
const user = {
  id: 42,
  username: "usrname",
  info: {
    fullName: "John",
    age: 15,
  },
};

function foo({ username: usrnam, info: { age } }) {
  return `${usrnam} ${age} `;
}

console.log(foo(user));
```